# multiply fraction with what number to get a whole number?

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

I'm solving some programming puzzle and it has come down to this:

I've a fraction, say 12/13, and I need to multiply it with a smallest possible natural number (say x) to get a whole number. How do I solve for x?

I intuitively feel I need to use LCM to solve this but haven't been able to pin down on a method.

Comment: Your fraction is in decimal form? Binary form?

Comment: decimal, updated to remove confusion

Comment: 12/13 * 13 = 12. I guess you can follow  the pattern?

Comment: Isn't it $denominator/pgcd(numerator;denominator)$? It seems to simple, I not sure to well understand the question.

Comment: you sure 13 is the smallest such number?

Comment: If you don’t believe that $13$ is the smallest, try the 12 smaller numbers and see what happens. Mathematics is not only a deductive matter, but also an experimental.

Comment: yes for this problem 13 works, but not always, eg 12/18 * 6 is a whole number too

Comment: For $\frac{12}{18}$ it's worked with lower than 18 because the fraction is reductible, there is a common factor between 12 and 18. So you need to apply the formula $denominator/pgcd(numerator;denominator)$ so in this case 18/3 thus 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the fraction is allready reduce ($\implies gcd(num;den)=1$) the smallest $x$ is denominator.

Or to reduce the fraction you have to divide both num and den by $gcd(num;den)$ so the new denominator is $den/gcd(num;den)$.

So the smallest $x$ is $den/gcd(num;den)$.

Comment: ya that should work, why didn't I think of it!

Comment: @BlueFlame For a *proof*, see my answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque $(a,b)$ means pgcd? I'm new here, is that a common notation cause despite long maths studies I h'aven't seen it yet? And I put pgcd cause I'm french but what is the abreviation in Englsih?
Thanks for the demo. :)
To answer to initial question by just adding a final point to your demo saying that $b/(a,b)$ is the smallest $c$ that respect the last condition would be great, I think, even if it's quite obvious.

Comment: Yes, $\, (a,b) := \gcd(a,b)\,$ is standard number theory notation. The proof shows that $\,c\,$ works iff it is a multiple of $\,\bar b = b/(a,b).\,$ Clearly the smallest multiple $> 0$ of $\,\bar b\,$ is $\,\bar b\,$ itself.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\,\ c \dfrac{a}b\in\Bbb Z\iff b\mid ac\iff b\mid ac,bc\iff b\mid(ac,bc)= (a,b)c\iff b/(a,b)\mid c$